# How to get real ip on layer 4 by Nginx?

Tags: nginx, networking

**Client A**  -> **Nginx Server B** -> **Back-End Server C**

**Back-End Server C** needs **real IP of Client A.**

How to do to solve this?

Can I just config Nginx Server B to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I find some way on nginx.com.
See:

- [9:43 Passing the Client’s IP Address to the Backend](https://www.nginx.com/blog/tcp-load-balancing-udp-load-balancing-nginx-tips-tricks/#IpBackend)
- [IP Transparency and Direct Server Return with NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/blog/ip-transparency-direct-server-return-nginx-plus-transparent-proxy/)
- [Proxy Protocol](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/using-proxy-protocol/)